# How do CDN's work with a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cdn

So I read [this](https://www.cdnetworks.com/en/news/how-content-delivery-networks-work/4258) and the Rails docs regarding CDNs [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) and I'm still confused about a couple of things conceptually.

1. When do the Rails files like the controllers and models come into play?
2. How do you invalidate the CDN cache when an image updates?
3. But what about files with dynamic content say like a user's name and address. How is that handled?

This is my understanding. Please correct me if I misspeak:

First, when a request is made say to `myrailsapp.com`, the request first goes to the CDN because we now pointed the CNAME of myrailsapp.com to the CDN address (say it's `cdnmyrailsapp.com`). I guess the DNS servers understand to route those requests to the CDN. The CDN checks whether or not it has any content cached. IF it does not, I guess the CDN forwards the request to the actual server? That's when the controller for Rails is hit and a static asset or javascript file is delivered to the CDN. All future requests for that file now use the cached version on the CDN.

Comment: Normally, a request would come in and be routed to a controller.  It would get any data needed by any models in that action and then forward that data to the view.  This would then be grabbing any data from the CDN while loading the page for view.  Rails will then cache those assets via the fingerprint id it has from being precompiled.  Only when those assets are changed would it skip the cache.

Comment: The CDN is for caching assets (images, stylesheets, etc that don't change dynamically). The DNS doesn't know about the CDN, your app does because you set config.action_controller.asset_host on the env.file. So it's the rails app that "fetches" the assets from the CDN. Whenever you request something that is dynamic your app will create that on the fly. Caching at that level is done on the app itself and not through the CDN.

Answer (score 0):

`CDN` can only serve your static assets (compiled css and js files etc), not models and controllers. (you can get this precompiled files by [assets:precompile](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets))

Your server serve all dynamic content dyrectly without `CDN`.

Your files are placed on `CDN` domain (`http://c000000.cdn.rackspacecloud.com` for sample), your application left on your domain (you do not need CNAME).

For images you need manually send them ([fog-aws](https://github.com/fog/fog-aws), [fog](https://github.com/fog/fog) gems ) on upload.